# Cannot get to centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) using SwiftUI and CoreBluetooth

Tags: swiftui, core-bluetooth

I wrote code that works using CoreBluetooth and the old Storyboard methods. Trying to move up to SwiftUI. The problem is that I can get to the class but *centralManagerDidUpdateState* is never called.

Code Below:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    private let ble = BugBluetoothClass()
    
    var body: some View{
        
        Text("Let's do Bluetooth")
        .onAppear(perform: connectBLEDevice)
        }
    // Function call to get everything going.
    private func connectBLEDevice(){
        let ble = BugBluetoothClass()
        // Start Scanning for BLE Devices
        ble.startCentralManager()
    }
}
```

The Bluetooth class is as follows:

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth
import UIKit

// Main class. All the functions are in this class.
class BugBluetoothClass: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, ObservableObject {
    
    // Declaration of the central manager and peripheral.
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
    private var skyddaPeriph: CBPeripheral?

    // I get here and print out the string.
    func startCentralManager(){
        print("Function call to central manager") // NOTE: I get to here and see the printout.
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
        
    
    // However, I never get to here and see no printouts other than this weird error in the debug box:
    // 2020-07-24 12:17:11.973247-0500 Skydda Bug[1318:189993] [CoreBluetooth] XPC connection invalid.
    
   func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state != .poweredOn{
            print ("Bluetooth Error")
            // In the future the screen should update to prompt the user to turn on Bluetooth.
        }
        else{
            print ("Start Scanning")
            // Scan for every peripheral that has the Environmental Sensing Serice.
            centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [SkyddaPeripheral.bugServiceEnviroUuid], options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : false])
        }
   } // End centralManagerDidUpdateState
```

Comment: Don't create a new instance of `BugBluetoothClass` in `connectBLEDevice`, use the `self.ble` property. The local variable you are creating is just thrown away  when the function returns

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! I think I got it going based on you comments. What I did was change the ContentView struct to the following:

````
struct ContentView: View {

    let ble = BugBluetooth()
    
    var body: some View{
        
        Text("Let's do Bluetooth")
        .onAppear(perform: connectBLEDevice)
        }
    // Function call to get everything going.
    private func connectBLEDevice(){
        //let ble = BugBluetoothClass() <- I think this was the issue.
        // Start Scanning for BLE Devices
        self.ble.startCentralManager()
    }
}```
````